# Ignore element for touch events in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, touch

I have a `Window` with two `Image` elements: Back and Front. Obviously, Front has higher Z-index then Back. I also have `TouchMove` handler on Back. But the event is not triggering when Back is overlapped with Front in the touch point. So, how do I make touch to ignore Front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want touch or click events to fall through to an underlying control, set [IsHitTestVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) to false on the Front Image.

[Here's more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.110).aspx) on how hit testing works on UIElements.